# Trying to understand Google Cloud Platform functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a REST API for a mobile application.
I wanted to try GCP Functions to see if it could fit my needs.
Now I got some problems. I think I misunderstood something.

When I try a function locally with the firebase-tools, the server is recreating everytime a request comes to the function instance. I thought the instance would keep my server alive for some time.

I know that each instance can only process one request at a time. But I am scared that the time it loses recreating the server at every request is a lot.

I am sure there is something wrong in my understanding.

I just want to know how it works to make the best of it.

Thank you :)

Here is my main function with a nestjs server

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { AppModule } from './module'
import { loggerMiddleware } from './middlewares/logger.middleware'
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as express from 'express'

const server: express.Application = express()

export async function createNestServer(server) {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server))
  app.use(loggerMiddleware)
  return app.init()
}
createNestServer(server)
  .then(() => console.log('Nest ok..'))
  .catch(error => console.log('Nest broken', error))

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server)
```

**Edit:**

[Screenshot of the initialization logs when a request comes in the GCP function instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLIEi.png)

As you can see, the function ends before the end of the NestJS server initialization. And it is doing this initialization each time I make a request to this URL. Even if the NestJS server is up, it does not keep the state to the next call.

Comment: How exactly are you observing the behavior you describe?

Comment: I got some update,
This line:
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server))
 seems to take some time to initialize.
What I assume is that when I am doing a request, the nestjs server doesn't have the time to initialize in time before the function returns the response. What I get is an 404 error, the default response express responds with. Even when I am doing a lot of request.
In the console, for each call, I get the same initialization logs but the function ends before the initialization of the nestjs server ends.

Comment: So what I am thinking about is that each time a HTTP event comes to the Function Instance, the whole function is instanciated. NestFactory.create which is asynchronous do not initialize fast enough to change the behaviour of the express server via the ExpressAdapter. So the express server responds with a default 404 error because functions.https.onRequest get first the empty express server.

Comment: This is what it seems to me that this is not a great solution for high traffic API because each time a request is finished the server closes and recreates again a new express app when a new request comes in. And so it takes some times and resources.

Answer (score 0):

If your function takes a long time to execute, then Cloud Functions will spin up a new instance whenever there is no  existing instance idle and ready to accept the connection.  Eventually, when your function finishes, the instance that handled it will go idle.

Code that runs in the global scope of your code will be executed as part of the first incoming request.  It does not come "for free" in anyway.

For HTTP type connections, the concurrent access limit is based on the bandwidth required by your function, not its compute time.  You could have hundreds of instances concurrently operating on longer-running functions, as long as you're willing to pay the cost of each one.

It would be good to understand the [documented limits and quotas of Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

Comment: Okay I understand. The thing is that it calls everytime my function for each HTTP request. So it reinitialize the whole express server. Is it right ?

Comment: I tried to add a global.iteration to see if it increments each time a request is done. And it never increments. Like if the global scope is recreated too. What I am guessing is that the local emulator recreates an instance for each call (is it right too ?). If not, each first incoming request in a new instance would be wrong because the NestJS server won't have time to initialize properly (due to its asynchronous initialization). Thanks for your answer by the way :)

Comment: My final question is, is GCP Functions a great solution for big API meant for high traffic ?